# Are there any Ways to replace values that contatin specific words in Power Query?

Tags: replace, powerquery, custom-function, realm-functions

I'm having difficulties with using Power Query M-function.

The problems I'm having with is to make cells blank previously contains 'US Core shipping' on column 'promotion-ids'.

For example, there are 'US Core shipping A3JU1250912' 'US Core shipping A3JT982918'...

These words are all different but they have 'US Core shipping' in common.

So I want to make these words containing US Core shipping~ to blank.

Please help me solving this problem.

Attached below are advanced editor and current m-code on my columns.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to tell exactly what you want without a sample input and desired output

To erase content in specified column if it finds matching text, maybe try

```
#"Replace" = Table.TransformColumns(#"YourPriorStepNameHere",{{"YourOriginalColumnNameHere", each if Text.Contains(_,"US Core shipping") then null else _, type text}})
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! What I was looking for is a transformation that if a word 'US Core Shipping' is included then it is converted into blank, the rest are remaining as before.

Comment: see revised code above

Comment: I tried what you told me to do... But it makes some errors.

Comment: #"Replace" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Flitered Rows1",{{"promotion-ids", each if Text.Contains(_,"US Core shipping") then null else _, type text}})

Comment: The editor says that "Replace" has a error, doesn't this makes sense?

Comment: No it does not make sense. Your code is fine. You must have missed an ending comma on the prior row, or perhaps spelled something wrong in your column names or prior name row (For example **Flitered Rows1** might be **Filtered Rows1** )  I assume you end with **in #"Replace"**

Comment: Now it works but the one I intended to replace did not... Wonder why this happened